# What is this part in my Royal Enfield motorcycle speedometer unit?

Tags: diodes

My bike meter got stuck after replacing my battery with a new one. I think due to new battery something burned in the circuit. I have images of the same.

I have an electrician who can fix televisions etc. I thought he could fix the speedometer. He says the black chip (I think it's a diode, I am not sure though) got burnt. I am not able to find the part as I don't know what it is.

I am not an electrical engineer (just a computer programmer.) I would like to know what the issue is, though. So please pardon me for my half-knowledge (rather zero-knowledge.)

What does the symbol on it mean (one with the mirrored C and H without the horizontal line.) Is it a company symbol or scientific symbol - and what is this part? If I can get a replacement he says that he can fix it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: [*TZ for Transzorb. Transzorb is a trade name. These should probably use class letter D as they act like Zener diodes.*](https://www.pcblibraries.com/forum/common-pcb-reference-designators_topic728.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a unipolar TVS (Transient Voltage Suppression) diode. The package size and markings may be able to lead you to a replacement. It may be a [3.0SMCJ24A](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ds30818.pdf)

There is a non-zero chance that whatever killed the protective device (generically called a TVS) has killed more devices. If the proprietary microcontroller (MCU) U4 is fried, you're probably going to be out of luck as far as repair goes. If it's just the power supply parts or it was protecting an input line you may be okay.

The battery replacement is probably related in some way. Either because removing the battery allowed the supply voltage to rise very high or because the battery was connected incorrectly for a moment.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's really helpful. I was directionless before but now at least I can progress in the right direction. It would really help if you could guide me to find the specification of this part so that I can get the replacement.

Comment: @Dibakash If you refer to the datasheet linked to the part number you'll find full specifications.

Comment: Thanks. I got it. Looking at the marking it seems that YWW is 607 and the Product  Type marking code is HEZ which equates to 3.0SMCJ24A ( which you already shared in your answer ). I hope I got it correctly

Comment: I finally sourced it from Mouser India supplier - SM electronics which was referred to me by mouser India. I was able to get in touch with them & they provided me with 2 of these diodes (one as a backup). I am no electrical engineer but got the damaged diode replaced with the new one aligned properly on the board by identifying the cathode end & then soldering it. And tadaa! it works. I got my Royal Enfield meter repaired only for 4 Dollars ( 290 Rs ). It would have cost me almost 100 Dollars to get a new one ( around 7000 Rs. for the original one). https://imgur.com/689XC5s

Comment: Thanks once again.

Comment: Always good to close the loop with a happy story.